# How to backup block-chain network data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I implemented hyper ledger fabric network on single machine and I am worry about backup of ledger data.
As blockchain network is secure and transaction can not be altered but as a backed developer How can we secure data as backup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Create a new network or node which has access to the same channels as the node whose data you want to backup. This new node will then rebuild its ledger and state DB for all these channels.
2. Manual backup: Login to peers and go to `/var/hyperledger/production` and backup the folders like `chaincodes , ledgersData and transientStore`

You can refer to this JIRA [Add ledger backup/restore to Operations Guide](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-3364)